# What is the default font in R 's plot()?

Tags: r, plot, fonts

I can not find out what the default font for the `plot()` option in R is. I recall somewhere there it was *Helvetica* but I cannot find any source to confirm this idea. Does anyone know what the default font in the `plot()` option is and how do I change the font?

I know there is the `family` option but that is very limited in choice of font. I am also aware there is a `family` option under `pdf()` which defaults to *Helvetica* but this captures the graphical image so the font of my plot is determined by the font in the `plot()` option.

Anyone got any ideas? In particular, I am interested in making all the text (plot labels, axis labels, main title, etc) into the *Helvetica* font. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at the `extrafont` package for changing fonts: https://github.com/wch/extrafont

Comment: yes, it's Helvetica

Answer (score 3):

If your system is Mac or Linux, on the console you can type:

```
X11Fonts()
```

You'll see the default font device "Helvetica".

Comment: I do not see anythin except for the ">" which indicates incomplete command =(

Comment: OK, maybe that was an old version of R? Now it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

For changing the font, refer to this link: https://r-coder.com/plot-r/#Font_family
So if you'd like to make "all the text (plot labels, axis labels, main title, etc) into the Helvetica font", set the `family` parameter of `plot` to `Helvetica`. This worked for me. Hope it will be helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The description for `family` in the `par()` function indicates that per default the default font of the current device is used.